# how to simulate a symlink from a .py file to a .pyw file?

Tags: python, windows

I want to have 2 copies of my python script, one as `.py` extension and the other as `.pyw` extension (Windows version, no console)

That allows me to run the `.py` file and get output from console (from command line) and associate the `.pyw` file to graphical programs.

Of course, the worst option is to duplicate files, which works but maintainability suffers.

When I was using clearcase, I used to create a symlink from one file to another but symlinks aren't the best choice when managing a code base.

I could create a helper module that I import in both cases to share the maximum of source code, but I have a lot of scripts in that case, and I'd like a generic solution.

What's the alternative to copying the whole file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a generic solution that doesn't depend on the contents of the `.py` file.

Say I have a `foo.py` file and I want to create a `foo.pwy` with the exact same behaviour, let's create this `foo.pyw` file with this exact contents in the same directory:

```
import os

with open(os.path.splitext(__file__)[0]+".py") as f:
    contents = f.read()
exec(contents)
```

As one can see, the name `foo` is nowhere to be seen in the contents. The script takes the name of the script, changes the extension to `.py`, reads it and executes it.

With some simple scripting, one can easily replace all copies of `.pyw` files to reference the `.py` files with this exact content no matter the contents of the original `.py` file.

This saved a lot of hassle when we migrated from Clearcase to git and had to drop the symbolic links.